# How do I open Google Hangouts ports on my home router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, google-hangouts

I found this article to optimize Hangouts: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090?hl=en
I'm supposed to open up a UDP port range for best results.

I have a Linksys E3200 router which has a port range forwarding option (like this: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?vw=1&docid=cf08f54aefbe4d9f97cfb772d817bdf8_3699.xml&pid=96&slnid=3) but it asks for a specific IP address.

What if I have multiple devices? I don't want to have to assign static ip addresses for each device that will potentially use this (phone, computer, guest devices, etc.)

Comment: Thanks that seems right; if you want to put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what's port *triggering* is for. Use the next submenu item on your router's configuration menu. See [this kb article](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?vw=1&docid=82e45c13dbcb4ff189c9f3a455951f0b_21486.xml).

Comment: Any idea what trigger ports to use?